# "Configure TableAdapter tbl_users failed. Specified cast is not valid." - Error When Editing/Creating TableAdapter?

Tags: mysql, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Bit of a back story, I was using MySQL Server 5.X on an old server. Retired server and migrated all data to a new server with MySQL 8.0.11 (now 8.0.12) installed. Used Legacy authentication to reduce issues.

This seemed to work and all my programs open/ran as expected. I've been editing them and publishing without any issues as well, however in that time I have not had any reason to change any of the data sources.

I've gone to change the data source today though and can not get it to work for the life of me.

If I try and make any changes I get the error "Configure TableAdapter tbl_users failed. Specified cast is not valid.". Obviously the table name varies and this happens regardless of which table (even trying to add a new table that I've just created).

It seems to work though, but on closer inspection, the delete and update commands are not created which means if I try and run the application I just get errors.

I've currently got:
Visual Studio 2015
MySQL Connector Net 6.9.8
MySQL for Visual Studio 1.2.7

Thanks in advance for any help/ideas.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow - nice to have you. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to help keeping Stack Overflows content on the highest possible level and increase your chances getting an appropriate answer. Please provide the code you are have right now, otherwise we could not help you.

Comment: Hi @sebast26. There is no code? I'm doing this through the GUI. I'm getting the same error from a new project with nothing in.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

@A Tyler. I suggest trying to update the MySQL for Visual Studio and MySQL connector to the newest versions. Have you tried that?
I think this issue is somehow related with the one described here.
https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=31338

This bug dates back to version 5.1 of the connector and VS 2005... should have been fixed right now, but the symptoms are very similar.

Maybe you found any other solution?

Update:

I 'slept' with the problem and found a workaround on the next day. This does not really solve the issue but made it possible to continue with the project.

I went to the 'properties' window of a table adapter and manually edited select and update commands there. It caused the table adapter to reflect these changes and I could use the new table field in my program. For me, this is good enough.